# Android plugin for SpriteBuilder crashes Xcode 6.4

Tags: xcode, spritebuilder, apportable

After installing the latest [Android Community Plugin](https://store.spritebuilder.com/products/spritebuilder-android-plugin-starter), my Xcode 6.4 project created from SpriteBuilder crashes with the following:

> No Xcode.DVTFoundation.ExtendedPlatformInfo extension provided for
>   platform 'com.apportable.platform.android'

If I remove the SBAndroid folder from /Library, it no longer crashes. However I would like to build my project for Android so am looking for a fix. Thanks.

Update: I've since downloaded Xcode 6.1 (for which it doesn't crash) and will work on that for now